# how to connect edges to nodes in a image using minimum spanning tree approach

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I am doing my project on graph matching in hand written image, i want to represent a given word image in graph, am using the below algorithm

```
Algorithm:

input: Binary image B, Grid width w, Grid height h
Output: Graph g = (V, E) with nodes V and edges E
1: function Grid(B,w,h)
2: for i ← 1 to number of columns C = Width of B/w do
3: for j ← 1 to number of rows R = Height of B/h do
4: V = V ∪ {(xm, ym) | (xm, ym) is the centre of mass of segment sij}
5: for Each pair of nodes (u, v) ∈ V × V do
6: E = E ∪ (u, v) if associated segments are connected by NNA, MST, or DEL
7: return g
```

am already  find the center of mass using this am plotting the points after plotting the points i do not know how to add the edges to using minimum spanning tree approch

this my code

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
X=imread('i2.jpg');
imfinfo('i2.jpg')
figure,imshow(X)

b = imresize(X,[100,100]);
si = size(b,1);
sj = size(b,2);
figure;imshow(b);

% Binarization
th = graythresh(b);
I = im2bw(b,th);

w = 10;
h = 10;
c=si/w;
r=sj/h;
kl=bwmorph(~I,'thin',inf);
figure,imshow(kl)

R(:,:)=kl(:,:);
I=1;
U1=w;
J=1;
U2=h;
E=1;
for i=1:r
  for j=1:c
B(I:U1,J:U2)=R(I:U1,J:U2);
[x,y]=find(B==1);
CX=mean(x);
CY=mean(y);
CXX(E)=CX
CYY(E)=CY
T(I:U1,J:U2)=B(I:U1,J:U2);
J=J+w;
U2=U2+h;
E=E+1;
clear B x y    
    end

I=I+w;
U1=U1+h;
J=1;
U2=h;

end
imshow(R)
hold on

hold on
plot(CYY,CXX,'.c')
hold off
% CXX(isnan(CXX)) = [];
% CYY(isnan(CYY)) = [];

r = imread('empty.jpg');
n = imresize(r,[100,100]);
figure,imshow(n);
hold on

hold on
plot(CYY,CXX,'.k')
hold off
```

[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWitr.jpg)
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JzDO.png)

am plotting using the `CXX` and `CYY` values i do not know how to add the edges to plotted points using minimum spanning tree approach please give me some code it will help me to complete my project

Comment: Did you work through these examples (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.minspantree.html)?

Comment: Yes sir it is asking input Graph. I don't have graph. To give input as graph.

Comment: "Use the graph function to create an undirected graph object. For more information, see graph." https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.minspantree.html#inputarg_G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell from your question, but I'm assuming you want to represent a graph where all nodes are at coordinates `[CXX,CYY]` and the weight matrix is the distance between node `i` and node `j`

You can generate an adjacency matrix with `pdist2()`

```
A = pdist2([CXX,CYY],[CXX,CYY]);
```

Build a graph based `A` (*note that this graph carries no information about original location, only distances*)

```
G = graph(A,...);
```

Determine the MST for `G`

```
T = minspantree(G);
```

`T.Edges` will be a table of nodes `i` and `k` that are included in the MST, as well as their distance weight. You can use graph functions to visualize this, although it will only factor distance vectors, not original coordinate locations

Comment: sir, i am not getting any adjacency matrix after trying this A = 173.0219

Comment: Try `pdist2(CXX',CYY');`  `pdist` requires that rows=observations and columns=variables

Comment: sir, i will try this, at present am using matlab 2014a version graph function will not support in this version so i want to run this in matlab 2015 or 2016. i will inform you as soon as possible. please give me some time. thank you

Comment: sir, am getting error : Adjacency matrix must be symmetric.

Comment: i tried `A = pdist2(CXX',CYY');` after this G = graph(A) in this part am getting adjecency matrix must be symmetric.

Comment: `pdist2([CXX,CYY],[CXX,CYY]);`

Comment: @BrendanFrick I think you need to swap `CXX,CYY` in the second argument to `pdist2`

Comment: sir i am not getting expected graph, graphs plotting randomly, https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Qud.jpg  i want to represent the word in this form.

Comment: @raghu It's not necessarily random, you probably did not map the MST to the original coordinates. As I mentioned in my answer, the MST representation does not automatically consider original coordinate locations. You will have to apply the edges that you get from the MST to the original coordinates `[CXX CYY]` or include node coordinates as well as the distance weights when building your graph. More information on that can be found here (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html).

Comment: @beaker Are you sure? The documentation is a little confusing for `pdist2()` so I could be wrong, but I understood it as each column for `X` and `Y` were treated as a consistent variables. If I swapped the second column it would be treating `CYY` as the x-coordinates in the distance formula

Comment: @BrendanFrick You're right, I wasn't thinking straight. :)

Comment: @BrendanFrick sir, in my code am getting only nodes in the sense point on the image, which plotted with the help of CXX and CYY but i do not know how to connect these points on the image, in the above algorithm which am trying to implement they told the associated segments are connected by MST approach. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JzDO.png i want to represent the input image in this form Grid-MST

Comment: Sir please help me.

Comment: @raghu I'm sorry, but you need to be more clear and specific about what you have tried and why it isn't working. Additionally, I am not going to code your solution for you when there are many resources that outline how to implement a specific solution to your general problem. If you are getting stuck on graph implementation ( mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html ), I'd recommend posting a new question that follows these guidelines (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), once you have tried to implement your solution

Comment: Sir in my program am plotting points using CXX And CYY on word  image But I do not know how to connect those plotted points on image using minimum spanning tree strategy.

Comment: sir please suggest me some other way to two add edges using minimum spanning Startergy