# how to connect plotted point on word image each segment in a image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graph-theory

i am doing my project on graph extraction in hand written word in this i divided a binary image into equal segments using
 C = (width of image image / 10 )  and R = (height of image image / 10 ) word image divided into 'C x R' segments of equal size,  For each
segment sij (i = 1, . . . , C; j = 1, . . . , R) a node is inserted into the resulting graph and labelled by the (x, y)-coordinates of the center of mass (xm, ym) Formally, we compute the number of foreground pixel in segment sij, while xw and yw denote the x- and y-coordinates of the foreground pixels in sij. If a segment does not contain any foreground pixel, no centre of mass can be determined and thus no node is created for this segment.

in my code i compute the center of mass in each segments but i want to connect the each node on the image please help to solve this problem

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
X=imread('math.jpg');
imfinfo('math.jpg')
figure,imshow(X)

b = imresize(X,[100,100]);
si = size(b,1);
sj = size(b,2);
figure;imshow(b);

% Binarization
th = graythresh(b);
I = im2bw(b,th);

w = 5;
h = 5;
c=si/w;
r=sj/h;

% Skeletonised
kl=bwmorph(~I,'thin',inf);
figure,imshow(kl)

R(:,:)=kl(:,:);
I=1;
U1=w;
J=1;
U2=h;
E=1;
for i=1:r
  for j=1:c
B(I:U1,J:U2)=R(I:U1,J:U2);
[x,y]=find(B==1);
XX=mean(x);
YY=mean(y);
XXX(E)=CX;
YYY(E)=CY;
T(I:U1,J:U2)=B(I:U1,J:U2);
J=J+w;
U2=U2+h;
E=E+1;
clear B x y

 end

I=I+w;
U1=U1+h;
J=1;
U2=h;

end

imshow(R)

hold on
plot(XX,YY, 'g*');
hold off
```

in my code i am getting center of mass of foreground pixels in each segment

this is my output
[output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqguU.jpg)

help me add the plotted point on image as a node to resulting graph

Edited, 
[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qHk0.jpg)

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
X=imread('math.jpg');
imfinfo('math.jpg')
figure,imshow(X)

b = imresize(X,[100,100]);
si = size(b,1);
sj = size(b,2);
%figure;imshow(b);

% Binarization
th = graythresh(b);
I = im2bw(b,th);

%Skeletonised

kl=bwmorph(~I,'thin',inf);
figure,imshow(kl)

R(:,:)=kl(:,:);
%grid size 
t1=10;
D=100;
 I=1;
U1=t1;
J=1;
U2=t1;
E=1;
t2=D/t1;
%Z=1;
for i=1:t2
    for j=1:t2
 B(I:U1,J:U2)=R(I:U1,J:U2);
 [x,y]=find(B==1);
 CX=mean(x);
 CY=mean(y);
 CXXX(E)=CX;
 CYYY(E)=CY;
 CXX(i,j)=CX;
 CYY(i,j)=CY;

 T(I:U1,J:U2)=B(I:U1,J:U2);
    J=J+t1;
  U2=U2+t1;
E=E+1;
 clear B x y 

    end

I=I+t1;
U1=U1+t1;
J=1;
  U2=t1;

end
%plot and grid
figure,imshow(R)
hold on
M = size(R,1);
N = size(R,2);

a=t1; 
b=t1;
for k = 1:a:M
    x = [1 N]; 
   y = [k k]; 
   plot(x,y,'Color','white');
   set(findobj('Tag','MyGrid'),'Visible','on')
end
for k = 1:b:N 
    x = [k k]; 
    y = [1 M];
    plot(x,y,'Color','white');
    set(findobj('Tag','MyGrid'),'Visible','on')
end

plot(CXX,CYY, 'g*');
hold off
```

Sir please try this edited code.

Comment: Can you also provide a sample input image? Code is much easier to understand if it runs.

Comment: I guess plot(XX,YY,'k--','Markersize',10);

Comment: Sir, i am inserted my input image and edited code please run my code.and help me.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your result. The first code doesn't run (`CX` is undefined), the second code doesn't show the green dots. Please do not mess up your post by duplicating almost identical code.

Comment: Sorry Sir in my edited code I forgot to change in the line in plot function plot(XX,YY, 'g*'); please change this line and run the code once again

Comment: Please edit your original post to reflect this change.

Comment: Sir please try second one edited code.

Comment: I think you should change the order of `CXX` and `CYY`. Still the green dots are not exactly located at the same location as your output image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to [draw lines](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) between the green stars. This can been done as follows:

```
plot(CYY(isfinite(CYY)),CXX(isfinite(CYY)), 'g*-');
```

I removed the invalid values using [logical indexing](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?s_tid=srchtitle#bq7egb6-1), otherwise not all the connections are drawn.

[image]

Comment: thank you sir for this image is there any algorithm to connect those point using minimum spanning tree aooroach.

Comment: Please use your favorite search engine before asking a question. I think a colleague of you already asked the same question some days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259896/how-to-connect-edges-to-nodes-in-a-image-using-minimum-spanning-tree-approach?rq=1

Comment: Sir we are unable to find the way to add the  edges to points  using minimum spanning tree method.